# Scandit barcode scanner issue in Phonegap iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, barcode, barcode-scanner

I'm using Scandit Barcode scanner in Phonegap. I'm creating an iOS app

I have successfully implemented the scanner into my app and everything is fine till I scanned a qr code, it vibrated but it didn't show the page of the qr code I scanned, it just return back to my application.

(I followed the tutorial here: http://www.inno-swiss.com/post/view/24448/)

Can I know how do I resolve this? Here is my script for the scanner in my html.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function onBodyLoad()
    {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

function success(concatResult) {
    resultArray = concatResult.split("|");
    alert("Scanned " + resultArray[0] + " code: " + resultArray[1]);
}

function failure(error) {
    alert("Failed: " + error);
}

function scan() {
    // See ScanditSDK.h for more available options.
    cordova.exec(success, failure, "ScanditSDK", "scan",
                 ["kI0HjHANEeOZZ+IFvIjVQ1D5+g0sVUMkiAEQdYKlCMI",
                  {"beep": true,
                  "1DScanning" : true,
                  "2DScanning" : true,
                  "qr" : true,
                  "scanningHotspot" : "0.5/0.5",
                  "vibrate" : true,
                  "textForInitialScanScreenState" :
                  "Align code with box",
                  "textForBarcodePresenceDetected" :
                  "Align code and hold still",
                  "textForBarcodeDecodingInProgress" : "Decoding",
                  "searchBarActionButtonCaption" : "Go",
                  "searchBarCancelButtonCaption" : "Cancel",
                  "searchBarPlaceholderText" :
                  "Scan barcode or enter it here",
                  "toolBarButtonCaption" : "Cancel",
                  "minSearchBarBarcodeLength" : 8,
                  "maxSearchBarBarcodeLength" : 15}]);

}

app.initialize();
    </script>
```